# Spring Data Neo4j is not creaing a relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a repository method :

```
@Query("MATCH (original:Entity{id:{0}}),(n:Entity{id:{1}}) "+ 
        "CREATE (original)-[r:SIMILAR]->(n) "+  
        "RETURN original ")
public Entity connectSimilar(String original, String new);
```

which I'm using to connect entities in this service method :

```
@Transactional
    public Entity linkSimilarStory(String linkedTo, String linked) {
        System.out.println(linkedTo+" and "+linked);

        Entity original = this.findById(linkedTo);
        Entity newEntity = this.findById(linked);

        if(original != null && newEntity != null){

            if(this.checkIfSimilar(original.getNodeId(), newEntity.getNodeId())){
                System.out.println(original.getNodeId()+" and "+newEntity.getNodeId()+" are already Linked !!");
            }else{
                original = repository.connectSimilar(original.getId(), newEntity.getId());
                System.out.print("Entities linked successfully : "+original.getId()+" with "+newEntity.getId());
            }
            System.out.println(this.checkIfSimilar(original.getNodeId(), newEntity.getNodeId()));

        }
        return original;
    }
```

When I run the service method from a controller to link 2 existent nodes (I checked their existence with the println) :

```
Transaction tx = neoTemplate.getGraphDatabaseService().beginTx();
Node otherNodeToLink = others.get(new Random().nextInt(others.size()-1));
//System.out.println("Linking "+root.getProperty("id").toString()+" And "+otherNodeToLink.getProperty("id").toString());
storyService.linkSimilarStory(root.getProperty("id").toString(), otherNodeToLink.getProperty("id").toString());
tx.close();
```

I got the message `Entities linked successfully` with their Ids.

When I check using the neo4j console, no relationship is created!

Running the same query directly in the console, it creates the relationship.

Can't understand why it doesn't work with Spring data :(

**Edit :**

I tried also doing this :

```
Relationship rel = template.getNode(original.getNodeId()).createRelationshipTo(template.getNode(newEntity.getNodeId()), isSimilar);
System.out.println("Rel: "+rel.getType());
```

It shows Rel: RelationshipTypeToken[name:SIMILAR, id:7], but keeps not creating the relationship in DB!

Comment: Are "Entity" and "Story" supposed to be the same type between your POJOs and the graph itself?

Comment: Sorry, yes.
It was a modification I made to put the code in general case.

I edited the post replacing Story by Entity

Comment: Ok. And what is the return value of "connectSimilar" when you call it in that "else" block?

Comment: It's always false, as he's unable to add the relashionship

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear/specified in your post since you say that you get the "Entities linked successfully" message. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
@Query("START original={0}, n={1} "+ 
    "CREATE (original)-[r:SIMILAR]->(n) "+  
    "RETURN original ")
public Entity connectSimilar(Entity original, Entity new);
```

...since you already have the Entity POJOs loaded.  Then pass in the "original" and "newEntity" POJOs you have from the code.  You shouldn't be a need to look them up again.

Let us know if that works (I haven't tried this in an SDN project, but, the query looks about right; tweak as necessary).

Comment: I tried this
 @Query("START original=node({0}), n=node({1}) "+ 
  "CREATE (original)-[r:SIMILAR]->(n) "+  
  "RETURN original ")
 public Entity connectSimilar(Entity original, Entity newEntity);

I had the same result

Comment: And how are you calling connectSimilar?  And are you sure you're passing valid/correct objects into the method?

Comment: Please look at public "Entity linkSimilarStory" in the original post.
And yes CThe objects I pass are valid as I'm printing them after I call linkSimilar

Comment: I did and in the original it still has you passing the ID property string.  I just wanted to make sure that you made appropriate modifications.  Can't be too careful. And to be honest I've never tried using a "CREATE" statement in a @Query-annotated repo.

Comment: oh yes I pass the objects instead of ids